# Code prompt parameter is always <error-type> - VSCode with STM32 in MacOS

Tags: visual-studio-code, stm32

I am currently writing code for a project, specifically interfacing with sensors via an STM32board. I set the pins/peripherals etc. using STM32CubeIDE, then generated the code with the Makefile toolchain for programming in Visual Studio Code. Everything is compiling fine, but the parameters in the function in the code suggestion displayed when the code is entered are always displayed "< error-type >".

As shown in the first picture below, the parameter type is always "< error-type >"

[image: Get the status of error prompts]

But what is strange is that when I press the '**cmd**' key, it is recommended that the data type of the parameter can be displayed normally.

[image: Get the status of normal prompts]

I tried to change the configuration path but still can't solve the problem.
This is my path configuration.

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${default}",
                "/Users/tinyu/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.7.0/MyStm32/Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc",
                "/Users/tinyu/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.7.0/MyStm32/Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src",
                "/Users/tinyu/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.7.0/MyStm32/Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy",
                "/Users/tinyu/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.7.0/MyStm32/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include",
                "/Users/tinyu/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.7.0/MyStm32/Core/Inc"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/local/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-gcc-arm",
            "defines": [
                "USE_HAL_DRIVER",
                "STM32F4xx"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

I don't know what went wrong, please help me, no type hint is difficult for me.